# IERC20 Implementation question

Tags: solidity, blockchain

In solidity while working with the IERC20 Interface, what does `IERC20(address)` do?

Answer (score 0):

That means there is a contract that implements IERC20. So, you are saying to the contract "trust me, buddy, I know there are some functions that IERC20 has in `address`". So because of these, you don't need low-level encoding. You can just use this method to interact with other contracts.